# What is the warning I get after moving to a new server?

Tags: 7, theming

This is the warning that I've received:

```
Warning: file_put_contents(temporary://devel_themer/cs6782ec6bb66b8a6ebfd11530a1ce0d9d1ce55eba): failed to open stream: "DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed in devel_themer_store_krumo() (line 348 of /home/u894021300/public_html/sites/all/modules/devel_themer/devel_themer.module).
```

What is it?

Comment: What version of theme developer are you using?

Comment: it is `devel_themer-7.x-1.x-dev`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for file permission where this module is trying to write , especially the temporary folder: admin/config/media/file-system

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you move files/folders from one server to another then sometime permissions on those files/folders don't move as expected. So give required permissions to 'files' folder. For example,

chmod -R 777 sites/default/files/

As suggested by @4life, if you will go to 'admin/config/media/file-system' and try to save the settings, it will throw an error if the files folder don't have enough permissions.

Comment: It is never a good idea to make a directory world writable. Better would be the permissions 775 for the files dir, combined with the web-server group as the group (e.g. Apache, http, www, depending on your installation).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the sites/default/files/ folder was set to 775 ( not a good idea to have it set to 777 )
I had to delete the following folder :

```
rm -rf /tmp/devel_themer/
```

Then it worked !